# Creating a json file by PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json, post

I want to update the json file by overwriting the old one. I can export the data to a json string by using some jquery. And the data is stored in the variable **json_update** . But I don't know how to send the data to php.

```
   $(function () {
    $('#switcher').click(function () {
    var json_update = JSON.stringify($('#table-hover').bootstrapTable('getData'));
    $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "adding2.php",
             data: json_update,
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
                alert("success");

             }
         });
    });
});
```

And here is the **adding2.php** . Thanks for helping me.

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['json_update'];
$fileHandler = fopen('work2.json', 'w+');
fwrite('work2.json',$data);
fclose($fileHandler);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the data a parameter name before sending it:

```
var json_update = { json_update: JSON.stringify($('#table-hover').bootstrapTable('getData')) };
```

This will make it accessible in `$_POST['json_update']`

Answer (score 0):

The data you send from the client side (the value of `json_update`) is stored in `$_POST`, so just change `$data = $_POST['json_update'];` to `$data = $_POST;`.